# Optimization of a Packet Generation Script

Tags: python-3.x, scapy, packet, netflow

I have a dataset full of 250+ million entries of netflow data. My goal is to develop an efficient way of generating packets for this netflow data, and I've decided to use Scapy as my means of emulating packets. For each of the entries in my dataset, I've found that a vast majority of packets are sent between some time frame capping at five minutes, and some of these entries have packet net totals as high as hundreds of thousands!

So here's the issue: I'll need a way to keep track of thousands of different entries at once to ensure that each entries' packets are sent out at the correct delta time until all packets have been sent.

For example:
Let's say that we have 3 entries in our dataset. The first is 100 packets that spans 20 seconds. The next is 200 packets that spans 20 seconds. The last is 500 packets that spans 60 seconds. The delta time between each packet in our dataset is 0.2s, 0.1s, and 0.12s respectively (20/100, 20/200, 60/500). Now I have only three entries that need to deliver these packets at the rate of these delta times. An example of the first few packets of each entry appended to a list would be as follows: [0.0s from entry 1, 0.0s from entry 2, 0.0s from entry 3, 0.1s from entry 2, 0.12s from entry 3, 0.2s from entry 1, 0.2s (0.1 x 2) from entry 2, 0.24s (0.12 x 2) from entry 3, 0.3s (0.1 x 3) from entry 2, 0.36s (0.12 x 3) from entry 3, 0.4s (0.2 x 2) from entry 1]

What is the best system I can come up with that will allow this process to happen with all packets being outputted to the same list concurrently?

Thus far, I've tried simply going entry by entry (adding packets with correct delta times) and adding this to a huge list of packets, then going onto the next entry and so on and so forth. This method works, however not only are the packets out of timely order and in need of a sort algorithm, but it's extremely slow and takes 15+ minutes to resolve just the first 100 entries of this 250 MILLION entry dataset! I think that I could definitely pipeline this process as to work on appending multiple entries to the list at once, but I'm simply not sure how to go about doing so.

The current code is on my github, https://github.com/NolanRudolph/UONetflow/blob/master/PyScripts/netflowPackager.py, however I don't believe one needs to read over my code to solve this problem. I believe someone's vast knowledge of Python could definitely offer an optimized solution within seconds. I've heard about utilizing sets which has hashmapping, but I'm not sure how I'd integrate this into exporting a multitude of entries' packets in an efficient manner.

I can see how this question could become very confusing really quick, so please don't hesitate to ask clarifying questions. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!